# sending a sms text from an arduino UNO

Tags: android, arduino, sms

I'm trying to send a sms message to a cell phone from an arduino UNO, the things is that I receive the message from an Android app but when I try to directly send it to a sms message the arduino crashes.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial portOne(4,3);

SoftwareSerial portTwo(6,5);

#include "sms.h"
SMSGSM sms;


int numdata;
boolean started=false;
char smsbuffer[160];
char n[10]= "87423474";


void setup()
{

Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial){
  ;
  }

 portOne.begin(9600);
 portTwo.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("***** Prueba de envio de SMS y Bluetooth *****");
  //Start configuration of shield with baudrate.
  //For http uses is raccomanded to use 4800 or slower.
  if (gsm.begin(2400)){
    Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
    started=true;  
  }
  else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");

}

void loop()
{

 portTwo.listen();
 Serial.println("Entra a loop1");
 if ( portTwo.available() )
 {
   Serial.println("Entro a loop 2");
   int x;
   x=Serial.write(portTwo.read());
   char ConvirtiendoAChar[15];
   String string;
   string=String(x);
   string.toCharArray(ConvirtiendoAChar,15);
   Serial.println("Convirtio a char");
   portOne.listen();
   if (portOne.isListening()){
    Serial.println("Otro debug");
   if(sms.SendSMS(n,ConvirtiendoAChar))
   {
    Serial.println("\nEl mensaje se envió correctamente");
    }}
 }
 Serial.println("No entro a loop");
 delay(2000);
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `sms.h` you could have done the thing easily by directly sending AT commands to the SIM900 module. Even `sms.h` does the same but it encapsulates these methods. There could be some mismatch between the module and header.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

void setup()
{
  SIM900.begin(19200);
  SIM900power(); 
  // give time to log on to network.  
  delay(20000);  
}

// software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button
void SIM900power()
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(5000);
}

void sendSMS()
{
  // AT command to send SMS message
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");                                                        
  delay(100);
  // recipient's mobile number, in international format
  SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+0123456789\"");                                     
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("Hello, world. This is a text message from an Arduino Uno.");        // message to send
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println((char)26);                       
  // End AT command with a ^Z, ASCII code 26
  delay(100); 
  SIM900.println();
  // give module time to send SMS
  delay(5000);
  // turn off module                                     
  SIM900power();                                   
}

void loop()
{
  sendSMS();
  do {} while (1);
}
```